# "If only you can" or "if only you could"?

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions, subjunctives

For someone staying in a different country who wants to bring dogs on the plane, should it be phrased:

> If only you **can** bring dogs over the plane.

or

> If only you **could** bring dogs over the plane.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the **subjunctive mood**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood):

> ...the indicative *can* as in *He can do it now* has the subjunctive form
>   *could* as in *I wish that he could do it now*.

So, to use your sentence:

**Present Tense:**

> **You can** bring dogs on the plane.

**Subjunctive:**

> **If only you could** bring dogs on the plane.

This means that your second sentence is correct.

Also note that I have changed "over the plane" to "on the plane".